# fixed css menu not to overflow content

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have the following setup for a webpage:

[image: website sketch]

I want a menu in the sidebar to the right, but if I use fixed positioning different devices and screen sizes will let my content and my sidebar collide...

How can I set up the divs or whatever in my wordpress theme to make it possible?

currently I have

```
<header>
4x <div></div>
</header>
<content>
</content>
<aside>
<nav>
</nav>
</aside>
<footer>
</footer>
```

with CSS:

```
#header {
display:block;
background-color:inherit;
width:1024px;
}

#header div{
display:inline-block;
}

#headermenuAKAtheFIRSTdivOFtheHEADER {
margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
width:134px;
height:134px;
float:left;
background-color:#fff;
} 
#footer {
margin: 4px 0 35px 184px;
padding:10px;
width:667px;
border: solid 1px #9a7283;
background-color:#fff;
}

aside {
width: 164px;
height:164px;
margin-right:5px;
position: fixed;
top:241px;
left:35px;
border: solid 1px #9a7283;
background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `fixed` ? Can't you use `float left` and `right` ?

Comment: I want to have the navigation always on screen. so it should be staying at its place in the middle of the screen.
Can I achieve this sticky effect with float left?

Comment: Okay Ani, can you please explain which CSS feature to use?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nJJ8p/22/

Comment: @Ani that is not fixed. Fixed is when it remains in the same position in the window even if the user scrolls the window. See for yourself: make the output pane of the fiddle smaller until you get a scrollbar and scroll up and down.

Comment: So I guess I have to use Javascript to make this possible? something like this? [js_floating_menu](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html) or it there any way to do it just with CSS and without fixed positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to have a sticky menu only with CSS.

I opted to do a little JAVASCRIPT action and integrated this one, works like a charm: http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you want to know how to position it.

You can set the sidebar to fixed, and give the content a margin-right of e.g. 200px. This will make the content maintain a space of 200px on the right.

```
#content {
    margin-right: 100px;
    border: dotted 1px red;
}
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 90px;
    border: dashed 1px green;
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/BZ7Sr/1/